# How do you permanently assign a specific workbook to a variable

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I am trying to assign a workbooks range to a variable (curr_range) and then open another workbook later in the macro.  The issue is that, if I use thisworkbook or activeworkbook, it will work thru the last workbook opened, which is not the one Im needing referenced for that variable

```
prior_inpath = Range("PriorPath").Value
prior_Infile = Dir(Range("PriorPath").Value & "Alberta.csv")
prior_indir = prior_inpath & prior_Infile

myLookupValue = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("IRE_Calc").Range("ETF_Names").Value
Workbooks.Open prior_indir
set curr_range = activeworkbook.range("F:L")


For r = 1 To 4
    For c = 1 To 2
        prior_arr(r, c) = Range("l64").Offset(r - 1, c - 1).Value
    Next c
Next r

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("IRE_Calc").Activate


myLookupResult = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(myLookupValue, curr_range, 6, False)
```

Im trying to ue the variable in a vlookup, hence the need for a permanent assignment.  curr_range is not in IRE_Calc which is the last workbook opened.

Comment: `Dim wb as Workbook` then `Set wb = Workbooks.Open prior_indir`

Comment: ^^-- `Set wb = Workbooks.Open(prior_indir)`

Comment: ThisWorkbook should refer to the one that has the macro, are you sure it doesn't work?

Comment: Yep, this worked.  Seemed like when I tried earlier it gave me issues.  Was probably a typo.  Thanks a bunch

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim MyWorkbook as Workbook
    prior_inpath = Range("PriorPath").Value
    prior_Infile = Dir(Range("PriorPath").Value & "Alberta.csv")
    prior_indir = prior_inpath & prior_Infile

    myLookupValue = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("IRE_Calc").Range("ETF_Names").Value
    Workbooks.Open prior_indir
    Set MyWorkbook = ActiveWorkbook
End Sub
```

Alternative
Set MyWorkbook = Workbook.Open(prior_indir)